# Index '15' of dimension 1 of array 'uwind' above upper bound of 14 Command exited with non-zero status 2

Tags: fortran

I use Ubuntu 16.04, and I try to run a piece of statement but I get this error:

```
At line 318 of file Usrdef_Surface_Data.f90
Fortran runtime error: Index '15' of dimension 1 of array 'uwind' above upper bound of 14
Command exited with non-zero status 2
```

Could any one tell me what's wrong with this part?

I showed line 318 in bold .However, I dot think that problem is related to `uwind` itself.

```
SUBROUTINE usrdef_surface_data(iddesc,ifil,ciodatetime,surdata,n1dat,n2dat,&
                             & novars)
!************************************************************************
!
! *usrdef_surface_data* Define surface input data
!
! Author - Patrick Luyten
!
! Version - @(COHERENS)Usrdef_Surface_Data.f90  V2.1.0
!
! Description - rhone plume experiments
!
! Reference -
!
! Calling program - define_surface_data
!
!************************************************************************
!
USE iopars
USE syspars
USE timepars

USE inout_routines, ONLY: open_filepars
USE time_routines, ONLY: convert_date, log_timer_in, log_timer_out

IMPLICIT NONE

!
!*Arguments
!
CHARACTER (LEN=lentime), INTENT(INOUT) :: ciodatetime
INTEGER, INTENT(IN) :: iddesc, ifil, novars, n1dat, n2dat
REAL, INTENT(INOUT), DIMENSION(n1dat,n2dat,novars) :: surdata

!
! Name         Type     Purpose
!------------------------------------------------------------------------------
!*iddesc*      INTEGER  Data file id
!*ifil*        INTEGER  No. of data file
!*ciodatetime* CHAR     Date/time in data file
!*surdata*     REAL     Data array
!*n1dat*       INTEGER  X-dimension of data array
!*n2dat*       INTEGER  Y-dimension of data array
!*novars*      INTEGER  Number of data parameters
!
!------------------------------------------------------------------------------
!
!*Local variables
!
integer, parameter :: ncc = 14, nrr = 11, m=16791

INTEGER, SAVE :: iunit
INTEGER::i,j,k
REAL,DIMENSION(ncc,nrr) :: uwind,vwind,patm,tair,rh,cc
REAL, DIMENSION(ncc) :: x
REAL, DIMENSION(nrr) :: y
INTEGER, DIMENSION(7) :: iodatetime
REAL,  DIMENSION(m) :: param1,param2,param3,param4,param5,param6

character (len=200) :: STmp


procname(pglev+1) = 'usrdef_surface_data'
CALL log_timer_in()

!
!1. Open file
!------------
!

IF (modfiles(io_metsur,1,1)%iostat.EQ.0) THEN
   CALL open_filepars(modfiles(io_metsur,1,1))
   iunit = modfiles(io_metsur,1,1)%iunit
   modfiles(io_metsur,1,1)%iostat = 1
   READ (iunit,*)
   GOTO 1000
ENDIF



!
!2. Read data
!------------
!

 iodatetime(5:7) = 0 
  DO j=1,nrr
  DO i=1,ncc
     READ (iunit,*,END=99) iodatetime(1:4), x(i),y(j),uwind(i,j),vwind(i,j),  &
    & patm(i,j),tair(i,j),rh(i,j),cc(i,j)
  ENDDO
  ENDDO

!write(*,*) 'Pause',iodatetime(1:4)!,x(i),y(j),uwind(i,j)
!pause

 CALL  NARRinterpol(ncc,nrr,x,y,surdata,param1,param2,&
param3,param4,param5,param6,uwind,vwind,patm,tair,rh,cc,n1dat,n2dat,novars,m)


ciodatetime = convert_date(iodatetime)

Do k=1,m
i=mod(k,(n1dat-1))
if (i == 0) i=n1dat-1
j = 1+(k-i)/(n1dat-1)
!print*, i,j,k
surdata(i,j,1) = param1(k)
surdata(i,j,2) = param2(k)
surdata(i,j,3) = param3(k)
surdata(i,j,4) = param4(k)
surdata(i,j,5) = param5(k)
surdata(i,j,6) = param6(k)
END DO


1000 CALL log_timer_out()


RETURN

!
!3. Set end of file condition
!----------------------------
!

99 modfiles(io_metsur,1,1)%iostat = 3
CALL log_timer_out()

RETURN

!9001 FORMAT(4I2,5(2X,E11.4))

END SUBROUTINE usrdef_surface_data



!========================================================================
SUBROUTINE NARRinterpol(ncc,nrr,x,y,surdata,param1,param2,&
param3,param4,param5,param6,uwind,vwind,patm,tair,rh,cc,n1dat,n2dat,novars,m)
!************************************************************************
IMPLICIT NONE

INTEGER ::  novars, n1dat, n2dat ,ncc, nrr,m
REAL :: deltxi, deltyj
REAL, DIMENSION(ncc) :: x
REAL, DIMENSION(nrr) :: y
REAL,  DIMENSION(m) :: xx ,yy

REAL,DIMENSION(ncc,nrr) :: uwind,vwind,patm,tair,rh,cc
REAL, DIMENSION(n1dat,n2dat,novars) :: surdata
REAL,  DIMENSION(m) :: param1,param2,param3,param4,param5,param6


!* local variables:
INTEGER :: i,j,k
REAL :: g,f, x0i,y0j


x0i = 1898.748
y0j = -684.544
deltxi = 32463.0
deltyj = 32463.0


 OPEN (11,file = 'LonLat.dat')
  DO k=1,16791
   READ (11,*) xx(k), yy(k)
  END DO
 CLOSE(11) 


 DO k=1,m

  DO j= 1,nrr-1 
    IF((yy(k).GE.y(j)).AND. (yy(k).LE.y(j+1))) exit       
  ENDDO
  g = (yy(k) - y(j))/deltyj

   DO i= 1,ncc-1
   IF((xx(k).GE.x(i)).AND. (xx(k).LE.x(i+1))) exit
  ENDDO
  f = (xx(k) - x(i))/deltxi


print*, i,j,xx(i),yy(j),xx(k),yy(k)
```

line 318:

```
param1(k) = ((1-f)*(1-g))*uwind(i,j)+(f*(1-g))*uwind(i+1,j)&
+((1-f)*g)*uwind(i,j+1)+(f*g)*uwind(i+1,j+1)
```

the rest

```
param2(k) = ((1-f)*(1-g))*vwind(i,j)+(f*(1-g))*vwind(i+1,j)&
&+((1-f)*g)*vwind(i,j+1)+(f*g)*vwind(i+1,j+1)

  param3(k) = ((1-f)*(1-g))*patm(i,j)+(f*(1-g))*patm(i+1,j)&
&+((1-f)*g)*patm(i,j+1)+(f*g)*patm(i+1,j+1)

  param4(k) = ((1-f)*(1-g))*tair(i,j)+(f*(1-g))*tair(i+1,j)&
&+((1-f)*g)*tair(i,j+1)+(f*g)*tair(i+1,j+1)

param5(k) = ((1-f)*(1-g))*rh(i,j)+(f*(1-g))*rh(i+1,j)&
&+((1-f)*g)*rh(i,j+1)+(f*g)*rh(i+1,j+1)

param6(k) = ((1-f)*(1-g))*cc(i,j)+(f*(1-g))*cc(i+1,j)&
&+((1-f)*g)*cc(i,j+1)+(f*g)*cc(i+1,j+1)


!write(*,*) k,i,j,param1(k)

 ENDDO
End SUBROUTINE  NARRinterpol 
!************************************************************************
```

Comment: The error message is very clear -- the code has tried to access the 15th row of an array with only 14 rows.  Somehow your code has created the value 15 where it shouldn't have.  Your best bet at this stage is to break out your debugger and step through the code.  While I'm writing, I can't see line 318 in bold.  Further, asking anyone to debug as much as 318 lines of code is perhaps asking too much.  Read about [mcve]s.

Comment: You seem to print "i" and "j" just before the line that's a problem; I assume it shows that "i" is indeed equal to 15? Does it help to look at how the value of "i" evolves in and out of the preceding loop?

Comment: note the line addresses `uwind(i+1,..)` , so `i=14` would be out of bounds.

Comment: BTW Unassuming this is someone else's code, it is entirely possible it may have run on a good day without error if the compiler did not do bounds checking.  It is obviously a bug in the algorithm that needs to be fixed though.

Comment: the core problem may be in the input data. It looks like `xx(k)` is expected to be in the range `x(1)<=xx(k)<=x(ncc)`, if it is not you will get that error. Of course it would be better if the code actually checked that and gave a meaningful error message.

Comment: Thanks all. in reply to agentp comment, I have set i=1,ncc-1, which considers the i values up to 13. so I don't think it goes out of bound. any suggestion?

Comment: Did you also watch for j+1 evaluating to 15?

Answer (score 0):

in this part :

```
  DO i= 1,ncc-1
   IF((xx(k).GE.x(i)).AND. (xx(k).LE.x(i+1))) exit
  ENDDO
```

after the loop is done the value of `i` will be :`(ncc-1)+1`

here

```
param1(k) = ((1-f)*(1-g))*uwind(i,j)+(f*(1-g))*uwind(i+1,j)&
+((1-f)*g)*uwind(i,j+1)+(f*g)*uwind(i+1,j+1)
```

there is a part `uwind(i+1,j)`, the first index is `((ncc-1)+1)+1`which is `ncc+1` (therefor out of bound ).

Comment: Doesn't the value of `i` after the loop depend on whether we `exit`?

Comment: It does , but I'm guessing that condition is not true so the loop is going to continue till upper value (ncc-1). I mean you should assume that if the conditions never met then what would happen to i that is used as an index for uwind.